# ExtJs and StackTrace.js

Tags: extjs, stacktrace.js

I try to include StackTrace.js in my app but It didn't work.

I try with CDN putting :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stacktrace.js/1.0.1/stacktrace.min.js"></script>
```

in my index.html

But I have the following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stacktrace.js/1.0.1/stacktrace.min.js.map.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1841' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I also try to include all the source but it try to load some ressources when i load my page and I don't understand how to change the location...

Anyhow I don't understand how to properly include this lib in my app in Sencha Cmd properly way...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stacktrace.js/1.0.1/stacktrace.min.js.map...

Note that this is for the source map file and should not affect the libraries effectiveness.

I hope you can verify that `stacktrace.min.js` loaded in the Network tab of your browser console. If so, then perhaps you can try a [simple example from the docs](https://www.stacktracejs.com/#!/docs/stacktrace-js) and see if you get a stacktrace or an Error.

If you do get an Error, please post here a little bit more of your code and what you see in your browser console and I'll be happy to help further.

Comment: The tag is in my page (StackTrace, Stackframe [...] javascript objet are available). If I execute the first example: "Get a stack trace from current location", i get in the _console_ : `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stacktrace.js/1.0.1/stacktrace.min.js.map. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' [...] is therefore not allowed access.`  then the stacktrace (which seems to be correct). And more problematic in the _network tab_, I get a call to _stacktrace.min.js, 1 to _stacktrace.min.js.map_ and 4 to the current page! (which cause some unwanted load)

Comment: stacktrace.js is trying to guess anonymous function names and is getting the source of the page to do so. You can call StackTrace.get({offline: true}) in order to avoid all network requests.

Comment: It seems now that stacktrace-gps.min.js is doing the same think. If think the options passed to the ``get`` method are not forward to stracktrace-gps (I see the option is available in StrackTraceGps but I cannot set it to true as I didn't call it directly).

Comment: Hm... that is a bug if that is true. I'm afraid I can't reproduce it, however. Would you consider attaching a more complete example and submitting it to the project? https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js/issues

Comment: I try to build an exemple with ``codepne.io`` and it works as expected :(. But double check on my case and I style have some loading from stracktrace-gps.min.js... I did not get it. I include the file exactly the same way, via the CDN... Didn't catch the dam think which make the think wrong...